# Converting string or char to int

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm totally puzzled

```
string temp = "73";
int tempc0 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0]);
int tempc1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[1]);
MessageBox.Show(tempc0 + "*" + tempc1 + "=" + tempc0*tempc1);
```

I would expect: `7*3=21`

But then I receive: `55*51=2805`

Comment: Convert the chars back to string and you get your "desired" result: `int tempc0 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0].ToString());
            int tempc1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[1].ToString());` A char is numerical implicitely and this number is not related to the int-representation of your substring.

Comment: The fastest way to convert digit characters into ints is to use `temp[0] - '0'`. See my answer for an example of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the ASCII value for the character 7 and 3. If you want number representation then you can convert each character to string and then use `Convert.ToString`:

```
string temp = "73";
int tempc0 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0].ToString());
int tempc1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[1].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(tempc0 + "*" + tempc1 + "=" + tempc0*tempc1);
```

Answer (score 5):

55 and 51 are their locations in the ascii chart.
Link to chart - http://kimsehoon.com/files/attach/images/149/759/007/ascii%281%29.png

try using `int.parse`

Comment: Yes, it also needs ToString() `int.Parse(temp[0].ToString());`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I don't like to take all the fun out of debugging ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    string temp = "73";
    int tempc0 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0].ToString());
    int tempc1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[1].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(tempc0 + "*" + tempc1 + "=" + tempc0 * tempc1);
```

You have to do ToString() to get the actual string representation.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the ASCII codes for 7 and 3, which are 55 and 51 respectively.

Use `int.Parse()` to convert a char or string to a value.

```
int tempc0 = int.Parse(temp[0].ToString());
int tempc1 = int.Parse(temp[1].ToString());

int product = tempc0 * tempc1; // 7 * 3 = 21
```

`int.Parse()` doesn't accept a `char` as a parameter, so you have to convert to `string` first, or use `temp.SubString(0, 1)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This works, and is more computationally efficient than using either `int.Parse()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`:

```
string temp = "73";
int tempc0 = temp[0] - '0';
int tempc1 = temp[1] - '0';
MessageBox.Show(tempc0 + "*" + tempc1 + "=" + tempc0 * tempc1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting a character to an integer gives you the Unicode character code. If you convert a string to integer it will be parsed as a number:

```
string temp = "73";
int tempc0 = Convert.ToInt32(temp.Substring(0, 1));
int tempc1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp.Substring(1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `string temp = "73"`, your `temp[0]` and `temp[1]` are being [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) values.

From [`Convert.ToInt32 Method(Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871.aspx) method

> Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the
>   **equivalent** 32-bit signed integer.

That means converting a `char` to an `int32` gives you the unicode character code.

You just need to use `.ToString()` method your your `temp[0]` and `temp[1]` values. Like;

```
string temp = "73";
int tempc0 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0].ToString());
int tempc1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp[1].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(tempc0 + "*" + tempc1 + "=" + tempc0*tempc1);
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/pqzReY)**.